# automatic changing node and npm version to specified versions in the package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nvm, n

First: It is possible to automatically change the version of `node` and `npm` to the engine versions you specified in the `package.json` without manually run `n` or `nvm`?

Next: Is there a version manager for `npm`? Sometimes i cannot install some packages over the latest `npm` version (3.3.9) and musst change to version 2.9.1. i had this behavior by installing `bcrypt` in combination with `sails.js`, i had to install sails with the `npm@latest`, switch to `npm@2.9.1` (because of not finding lodash und `fsevents`) and install `bcrypt`.

my actual version change is following.

`npm install -g npm@2.9.1` or `npm install -g npm@latest`

But in some cases he doesn't add `npm` to the `PATH` variable after switching versions. So a package like n would be very nice.

but search for a similar mechanism like the package n (node version manager).

By the way, do you prefer `n` or `nvm`? I use n, because it does what it does and it works nice.

Node / NPM is so mighty and i want to introduce it to my company, but i need some tools for automation and guarantee that it works :)

Thank for the coming answers.